# Regular Expression Validation - Range Validation with minium length value and undefinited maximum length

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I use ASP.NET and C#.

I have a `RegularExpressionValidator` control on a Web Form Page, and I use a custom `regex` to check the **minim an maximum length for an input TextBox**.

I need to modify the regex to check just a minimum value but set as UNLIMITED the maximum value. So validation for a TextBox would be only for the minimum length.

Any ideas how to change by regex?

Here my code. Thanks for your help!

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxRegularExpressionValidatorHighlightMaxLengthDisplayer"
                        runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxSummaryInputer" ErrorMessage="Highlight is too long or short. Change the field accordingly."
                        ValidationExpression="^.{64,256}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change it to be:

```
 ValidationExpression="^.{64,}$"
```

Comment: @GibboK glad to hear :) I recommend you to read this about regex: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use range validator instead og regular expression validator, in the range validator you can specify range with type="string" method. like this....

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="range" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="65123" Type="String" />
```

Comment: this simply does not work - if you try it, it will fail on string type input that matches the range.